# How should I connect a GCFI outlet and switches to the wires in my bathroom?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

In my son's newly purchased house bath there is a box with 2 switches and an outlet. I am replacing the switches and changing the outlet to a GFCI.

There is power coming in on a 12/3 cable, 12/2 cable going to the vanity light, exhaust fan and a 12/3 cable feeding an adjacent bath.

My son had already removed the old equipment leaving me nothing to compare the wiring to. Can someone please give me the proper wiring for this situation? I’m not interested in the switches or the feed to the other bath being protected by the GFCI.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: There isn't any standard to wiring stuff like that.  The last electrician communicates it to the next electrician by *how they are attached to devices*.  Tearing out all the devices without taking notes or marking, simply destroys that information and it's gone.  Reconstructing it is typically non-trivial, but sometimes you get lucky and the remaining wires tell the tale.

Comment: @brhans, "bath" is shorthand for "bathroom" in the building industry. He doesn't mean the tub.

Comment: Chances are good some photos would lend insight. Don't move the wires any more than they already have been. Get clear, well-lit shots and post them up. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: You will need to identify the feeder from the service panel and where all the wires go, how many breakers feeding the 12-3 if we don’t get any updates the question will probably be closed. A basic multi meter can be used to identify the kind of feed single breaker or multiwire circuit type. A non contact indicator tester can provide some help but these are not always correct.